# Significance Test for ML Classifier Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, validation

I have a binary classifier that outputs continuous values. If the output is $\ge0$, then it is a positive class prediction, otherwise it is a negative class prediction.

After training this binary classifier and evaluating it using a test set, I want to apply it to unlabeled data to predict its class. Is there a way to validate the statistical significance of the prediction for this unlabeled data. Intuitively, a prediction of $5$ is much more likely to actually be positive than a prediction of $0.1$, but is there a way to apply a t-test or something of that nature to show this?

Comment: What would be your null hypothesis in this case? Why do you think you need a significance test at all?

Comment: Do you not have labels at all? Then how do you know of your prediction is correct? I have my prediction about tomorrow’s stock market, but until I get the closing value, it’s just a prediction. We won’t know if I made or lost money until we get the truth value.